# Upgrade Symfony from 2.1 to 2.3 : where session is started?

Tags: php, session, symfony, migration, symfony-2.3

I am a symfony project in Symfony 2.1

When I migrated to 2.3, it seems a service starts the session before.
So my code can't fix session id.

Is there a way to find which service use session before ?

Comment: Does not method `setId` do the thing you want? [Session api](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html#session-api)

Comment: No. I get an "Cannot change the ID of an active session" error.
And if I remove the line with setId() I get the "Failed to start the session: already started by PHP ($_SESSION is iset)" error.

Comment: set `session.auto_start = 0` in `php.ini`

Comment: @forgottenbas already done (and done by default).
I'm pretty sure one of bundle we use and/or cause do it. But I dont know how to find it (and where)...
Especially as this is due to symfony 2.3 (and / or modification we put to works with 2.3), because I didnt meet this problem when I had  symfony 2.1

Comment: which moment you modified session?

Comment: With the setId() => in a controller

Comment: Take a look at this https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/issues/555 As far as I can see this is the same problem as you have. And maybe this can help you also http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/session/php_bridge.html

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the answer, but my idea would be to create a request listener, set it's priority to a high value, and try to set there the id. Ex:

services.yml

```
request_listener:
    class:  My\Bundle\Service\Listener\RequestListener
    arguments: [ @session]       
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest, priority: 9 }
```

and the request listener:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

class RequestListener
{
    protected $session;

    function __construct(Session $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
            $this->session->setId(xx);
    }
}
```

Comment: With this kind of listener, it doesnt change the behavior as in first comment.
With the set id (those in controller) I get  "Cannot change the ID of an active session" and if I remove the the set Id on the controller I get "Failed to start the session: already started by PHP ($_SESSION is iset)" . All that with this request listener and correct session id.

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand what you mean by "All that with this request listener and correct session id" :-s. Anyway, I know it is hard to change the way Sf handles the session.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your answer and comment.

Indeed the Symfony 2.3 add new listeners and these was the source of the problem.